# Why this code doesn't hide the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show some input checkbox inside a form only if a certain other checkbox is checked.

**I´ve read about .show() and .hide() but I want to do it changing the css selector.**

My problem is that the hidden selector isn't hidden at all: It is printed out without any regard of the checkbox.

Please note that this is just a test, I'm learning jQuery and wanted to try it out.

This is what I've tried ([**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rosamunda/3C4GB/))

### HTML FORM:

```
<form name="ejemplo">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="idCheckbox1" value="check" checked>Sí? &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="idCheckbox2" value="check">No &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <div id="ocultar">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="idCheckbox3" value="check">Tal Vez</div>
</form>
```

### JS

```
    //Usamos jQuery para mostrar un elemento condicionalmente
   if ( $("input:checkbox[id=idCheckbox2]:checked") ) 
       $("#ocultar").css("display","inline");
    else
       $("#ocultar").css("display","none");
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I´ve corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `id` is unique you can use

```
$("#idCheckbox2")
```

instead of

```
$("input:checkbox[id=idCheckbox2]")
```

To check if the checkbox is checked, you can use **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**:

```
if($("#idCheckbox2").is(":checked"))
    $("#ocultar").css("display","inline");
else
    $("#ocultar").css("display","none");
```

You also need to use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event to keep track when your checkbox has been changed and shorten your code using ternary operator:

```
$('#idCheckbox2').change(function () {
    $("#ocultar").css("display", this.checked ? 'inline' : "none");
}).change();
```

The `.change()` at the end is used to trigger the `change()` event on page load and execute the code if your checkbox has been checked by default.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TA242/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a change event handler so that the display properties will up updated based on checking/unchecking of the checkbox

```
$('#idCheckbox2').change(function(){
    $("#ocultar").css("display", this.checked ? 'inline':"none");
}).change();//used to set the initial state based on checkbox value
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B9Xte/)

You can even use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to simplify the code like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B9Xte/2/)